# Why does Software Center fail to open with a "could not get usefulness..." error?

Tags: software-center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software center not opening](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185117/software-center-not-opening)

When opening software center, the operation is stuck after opening the window and upper bar. The error message when launching from terminal is:

```
2012-06-19 12:53:33,684 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
```

Comment: I got it by myself.. this fixed the problem for me.. in terminal i typed ::  rm -r ~/.cache/software-center

Answer (score 3):

The OP solved this by opening the terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and typing:

```
rm -r ~/.cache/software-center
```

- When doing this, it's very important to not accidentally have a space after `~` or the first `/`. **If you do, it will remove all the files in your home directory, which generally includes all your documents!**
- An alternative command to run, which doesn't turn into such a bad thing when typed slightly wrong, is this:

  ```
  cd ~/.cache; rm -r software-center
  ```